# Is ExtensionContext.globalState a permanent storage?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I search over the internet, [VSCode documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ExtensionContext.globalState) and here in stack overflow, but I can not find a place explaining if `ExtensionContext.globalState` is a permanent storage solution or not.
With permanent I mean:

- it survives across VSCode updates
- it survives across extension updates
- ideally it survives to extension uninstalls - installations

Which of the above points does the mentioned `ExtensionContext.globalState` fulfill?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, `globalState` does survive VSCode and extension updates. Even though it may not be documented, it's definitely intended to work that way, as you can see when looking at issues like [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/68468) where storage was being migrated due to some internal changes (however it sounds like it was possible to lose storage by skipping a version / going from 1.29 to 1.31 directly and due to some issues in the migration code).

Regarding extension uninstalls - this one is easy enough to test yourself, so I tested this on an extension I maintain that uses global storage. The global storage value was still present when after an un- and re-installation.